# Borderless NSWindow with rounded corners

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow

I am creating a custom `NSWindow` with no title bar and am using `NSBorderlessWindowMask` to make it completely borderless. The problem I have with this however is that the window has sharp edges. As well as this there is no resize control.

How would I give a borderless window rounded corners?

> This is **not** a duplicate of [this
>   question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003975/round-corners-on-a-borderless-nswindow) as that question was more
>   about removing the title bar and it
>   currently holds no answers.

Comment: You might be looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940019/nswindow-with-round-corners-and-shadow/27613308#27613308). This is bordered style, but seems close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the window totally transparent and handle drawing everything yourself. The sample I have is for an OpenGL view, but it should work for a Quartz view or Cocoa view as well.

Add the following to the initializer of your NSWindow subclass where you create the new window using the NSBorderlessWindowMask constant.

```
[self setOpaque:NO];
[self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

You will probably have to draw the resize control yourself. The sample I took this from is a full screen window so resizing isn't necessary.

Good Luck.

Comment: Where would I handle drawing everything?

Comment: In your view class' -drawRect: override. You will need a drawing context to draw into so subclass either NSImage or NSOpenGLView. I misspoke, the code I gave you in my answer should be in your NSWindow subclass. You will also need a custom view subclass to do the drawing.

Comment: Going on what you gave me, I was able to find this tutorial on Cocoa With Love. Consider your answer accepted! http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been reading Cocoa With Love for years but didn't know about that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a window with rounded corners is to place a `NSBox` into the window as these boxes have customizable rounded corners and customizable borders. If you then set the window to non-opaque and the background color to transparent ("clear color"), you have a `NSWindow` with rounded corners that draws a normal window shadow (even on older systems where such a window would otherwise not have a shadow). Most of it can be done in Interface Builder. [See here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60383955/15809).

Answer (score 0):

Only titled windows get the rounded corners. So the only thing you have to do is this:

```
window.styleMask = [.titled]
window.titleVisibility = .hidden
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

This should be the minimal configuration for a rounded window without a title bar.

Comment: But then you're stuck with a bottom border. That's what I've found. When I turn the bottom border off, I get an error compiling.   "regular border style windows not using Autosize for the Top Content Border property (Other values are explictly unsupported at runtime and will lead to an exception"