# How can I have border effect shadow on my window?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am using `window.styleMask = [.borderless]` and it makes the white shadow effect goes away, how can I use `borderless` without losing that white shadow effect?

Here is pic to show the issue:

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the "white shadow effect" is part of the border. You could always render one yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSWindow with round corners and shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940019/nswindow-with-round-corners-and-shadow)