# Remove OS X Application Toolbar in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

My application is such that it does not require the tool-bar. It is very simple in nature and is controlled 100% by keyboard actions (one at a time, even). So while I know it's generally accepted that you should leave the toolbar in place, this time I feel that it actually hampers the UX of the program. So, I was wondering if it's possible to actually remove the tool-bar from my program?

It's easy to remove the traffic lights [ o  o  o ] from the bar, and there's no Title, but the space is still there, and the application simple looks 'off' with the extra space.

Any pointers are much appreciated, as I've looked around with the following queries:

- How to remove the toolbar in an OSX application in XCode / Objective-C.
- How do I remove the toolbar in an OSX application in XCode / Objective-C?

and a few others without much success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say toolbar, but I think you mean the window's title bar. This previous answer should work for you. The top answer is the way to do it, and the second answer is an argument against doing it.

[Hide NSWindow Title Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018147/hide-nswindow-title-bar)

Comment: Alright, I see now that doing so removes all of the built in control of the window. So essentially it becomes a matter of hand-coding all of OSXs built in window handling, which is actually a major part of this application. Thanks for the pointer, sorry I didn't get the wording correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep title bar, but just want to customize it (including close, minimize and maximize buttons), you can use [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) component.