# Adding tabs to a window with no titlebar

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, tabs

I am trying to add tabs to a window with no titlebar. Setting `self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true` or disabling the titlebar blocks system tabs, and I can't find any Safari style tabs in the object panel.

On a normal window, you can create tabs by making two windows and selecting Window > Merge All Windows

This can be seen below the default "Show, Minimize, Zoom" that Xcode makes.

[image: Option shown]
[image: Normal window, tabs can be created]

On a borderless window, the option is not there and is not in first responder

[image: Option not shown]
[image: Borderless Window, Tabs are not allowed]

On a window with a titlebarAppearsTransparent, the option is not there and is not in first responder.

[image: Option not shown]
[image: titlebarAppearsTransparent window, Tabs are not allowed]

Without using `Merge all Windows`, there doesn't seem to be a builtin Safari style tab view. The tab view that is builtin uses system preferences style tabs and I am trying to get Safari/Finder/System style tabs. I don't want to use custom rendered tabs because they won't work and feel the same way the system tabs do.

Comment: Not tested, but I would try to use `yourMainWindow.addTabbedWindow(yourChildWindow, ordered: .above)` triggered by a custom menu. Just an idea.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018147/hide-nswindow-title-bar works for you. It's objective-c code but it should translate to swift pretty easy.

Comment: @Moritz This doesn't work on a window with `styleMask = .borderless`

Comment: @FelisPhasma I know how to hide the titlebar, but I am trying to put tabs on  this titlebarless window. Although it seems like it could have an answer because it talks about keeping the bottom bar, nothing is accepted and none of it keeps tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When window-tabbing is enabled, windows can be grouped in tabs as long as all share the same tabbingIdentifier. AppKit automatically calculates such identifiers based on some context inspection but ignores windows with the `titlebarAppearsTransparent` option set.
Therefore just set your own `tabbingIdentifier` and you're happy to go.
As a side-note: The user preferred  tabbing behavior for newly created or opened documents can be set in *System Preferences > Dock*.

```
window.styleMask |= NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView;
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;
window.tabbingMode = NSWindowTabbingModeAutomatic
window.tabbingIdentifier = @"MyDocumentWindow";
```